# Notify-send notifications appearing under window

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, notifications

I've written a shell script to ensure that my daughter doesn't play Minecraft on her Raspberry Pi for more than 60 minutes in a week :).  Part of the script uses `notify-send` to pop up notifications warning of the remaining amount of time.  However, both `notify-send` and `notify-send --urgency=critical` notifications appear under the Minecraft window, so that only a small bit of grey is visible over the window titlebar.  Why does this occur, and is there anything else I can do to make a visible warning (in case there are alternatives to `notify-send`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use 'notify-send', notification appearance is decided by two *other* components:

- the [notification server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications#Notification_servers) which creates the popup windows with a certain appearance (e.g. notification-daemon, notify-osd, xfce4-notifyd, dunst, dzenify, lxqt-notificationd);
- the window manager which ultimately decides each window's position and z-order on the desktop.
- ('notify-send' doesn't show anything itself, it just submits a "show notification" request.)

So either the current notification server isn't trying hard enough to make the popups always on top, or the window manager has decided that full-screen windows have priority regardless, or the window manager (or Xorg itself) is somewhat buggy.

You can experiment by changing the notification server – first kill the process for the current one (and remove it from the desktop environment's "autostart"), then install and launch a new one (e.g. by running `/usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd &`).

To determine which process ID is currently acting as the notification server, use:

```
gdbus call -e -d org.freedesktop.DBus \
              -o /org/freedesktop/DBus \
              -m org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID \
                 "'org.freedesktop.Notifications'"
```

As an alternative to notify-send in general, you could use programs which create a regular window with some text – for example, xmessage; gxmessage; or zenity. They are perhaps more likely to behave correctly.

Comment: You were right - `dunst` works fine, much better than `notification-daemon`.  I did try xmessage etc. earlier, but they had the same problem (appearing under the full screen window).